# How can I get previous value of a TextView add to the current TextView value and so on?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add the TextView with previous value and so on. The TextView gets updated every 5secs (real-time) and it should add on to the previous TextView value and update. For example, value at T1 = 1 -> value at T2 = 1 => at T2 TextView should update to the total of T1 and T2 = 2. Also I'm dealing with float numbers. And I'm pulling the data from FireBase.

Thank you in advance.

```
    private TextView tempMNData;

    private FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference myRef1 = database.getReference("GCU/temperature") ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_extraction_page);

        tempMNData = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temperatureMNData);


       myRef1.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

               String value = snapshot.getValue(String.class);

               tempMNData.setText(value);
    

           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

           }
       });

     
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need the previous data to be added to the new ones. If so, then this might work for you:

```
String value = snapshot.getValue(String.class);
value2 = value2 + value;
Value2 = value2.ToString();

tempMNData.setText(value2);
```

String value2 = 0

how its should working:

you take some data from FireBase, for exemple first data its "1", second "7", third "12".

in code: value = first data from FireBase, value2 = 0.

value2 = 0 + 1;

show value2 in TextView

repeate it

value2 = 1 + 7; //8
TextView(value2);

and last time

value2 = 8 + 12; // 20
TextView(value2); // show 20

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.

That's exactly what I'm seeking help for. I have tried using the method you have mentioned. But it's printing like null23.8824.07 (where 23.88 is the first value and 24.07 is the second value). Also when i'm declaring String value2 = 0, its throwing an error suggesting me to change to int. And if I do that the app is crashing.

Comment: Can you show me your layout, i try create code

Comment: You mean the xml?

Comment: yes! But now i think you can Convert your data from FireBasw, try use next code:

String value = snapshot.getValue(String.class);

value = Convert.ToInt32(value);

Comment: <TextView
            android:id="@+id/temperatureMNData"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:text="0.0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

Comment: Above is my XML file. Apologies for the format. I was trying using the ConvertToInt as well but no luck.

Comment: So I made a mistake in my code, I forgot to use .ToString when we add the values. Try it value2 = value2.ToString();.  After value2 = value2 + value;

Comment: I tried different approaches, but none of them seems to be working. It either crashing the application or its just concatenating the numbers.

Comment: Try use int value in Firebase

Comment: Im sorry I didn't understand what you meant to use int value in FireBase. I'm sending float value to Firebase from MicroController.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, that actually answered my question.